# A lightweight approach to processing Django Queryset data

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I am looking for a optimal way to perform simple data processing from Django Queryset. I would like to not need to install libraries with high volumes like Pandas or numpy. The number of rows in Queryset should not exceed 2000. The idea is to perform basic functions such as x1, x2, x3 below. I want to avoid a separate database query for each of them so I'm thinking to get all this data once from the database, convert it to a standard data structure and calculate the results.

Queryset Sample:

```
T1_id    T2_id   T1_value    T2_value
  1        2        2           0
  3        5        0           0
  4        1        1           1
  2        7        0           3
```

Pandas code equivalents:

```
data = [[1, 2, 2, 0], [3, 5, 0, 0], [4, 1, 1, 1], [2, 7, 0, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['T1_id', 'T2_id', 'T1_value', 'T2_value'])

x1 = df[df['T1_id'] == 1]['T1_value'].mean()  # Mean of T1_value from rows where T1_id == 1
x2 = df[df['T1_id'] == 1]['T2_value'].sum()  # Sum of T2_value from rows where T1_id == 1
x3 = len(df[df['T1_id'] == 1])  # Number of rows where T1_id == 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily calculate these all with an [**`.aggregate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Count, Sum

MyModel.objects.filter(T1_id=1).aggregate(
    x1=Avg('T1_value'), x2=Sum('T2_value'), x3=Count('*')
)
```

this will return a dictionary that maps the items to the corresponding result, for example:

```
{'x1': 14.25, 'x2': 1302, 'x3': 42}
```

By doing this as a query, the database will calculate this, and database is closer to the data and often is optimized to make aggregates, so will likely outperform pandas quite significantly. Especially since if we would use pandas to aggregate, it would first need to move the data from the database to pandas, which will likely take longer than the database determining the values directly.

Comment: I didn't specify it but I will need several filters at the same time i.e. mean, sum and count for objects.all(), objects.filter(T1_id=1), objects.filter(T2_id=1), objects.filter(T1_id=5), objects.filter(T2_id=5). Is this approach to combine all these values into one complex queryset still better than calculating it in the backend?

Comment: @Jacek: you can also use `Avg('T1_value', filter=Q(T1_id=1))`, `Sum('T2_value', filter=Q(T2_id=5))` to thus filter differently *per* aggregate, and yes, likely that will still pay off compared to pandas. The main problem is that using pandas means the database will need to return (almost) all records, and that can be huge and thus requires a lot of work from the database to generate the response, and from pandas to load the result. This will very likely take more time than the aggregate itself.